# Decapitalize UTF-8 special characters in R

Tags: r, string

After I scraped a list of names, I have the following name in R:

```
DAPHN\303\211 DE MEULEMEESTER
```

If I use the function tolower, all the letters are set to lowercase, but not the special characters. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: it works `tolower("DAPHN\303\211 DE MEULEMEESTER")` ddisplays `"daphné de meulemeester"`

Comment: This may be locale related. What do you get from `Sys.getlocale();`?

Comment: I get the standard "C", should I set this to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your locale is C. Non-ASCII special characters and their letter-case classifications are not recognized under that locale. You should be able to get it to work by switching to a UTF-8 locale:

```
Sys.setlocale(locale='C');
## [1] "C/C/C/C/C/en_CA.utf-8"
tolower('DAPHN\303\211 DE MEULEMEESTER');
## [1] "daphn\303\211 de meulemeester"
Sys.setlocale(locale='en_CA.UTF-8');
## [1] "en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.utf-8"
tolower('DAPHN\303\211 DE MEULEMEESTER');
## [1] "daphné de meulemeester"
```

`en_CA.UTF-8` makes sense for me because I'm in Canada, but if you're in the United States (for example) you'll probably want `en_US.UTF-8`. I think for any country you should be able to replace the `CA`/`US` with your two-letter country code to get the most appropriate locale for your location.

Comment: Thanks this works. But if I upload it to SQL now, some characters became even weirder, like a copyright symbol. Do I have to change a setting in SQL to?

Comment: What's your DBMS? How are you uploading? How are you viewing the text after the upload?

Comment: I am starting to figure it out: I changed my locale from "C" to "UTF-8", and I can now use some regex code such as [[:upper:]], which works as well on special characters. I changed the encoding in my MySQL database to UTF-8 and now the characters are stored correctly in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Without changing your system locale, you can do locale-aware text transformation using the `stringi` package:

```
library(stringi)
her_name <- "DAPHN\303\211 DE MEULEMEESTER"
stri_trans_tolower(her_name, locale="en_CA")
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been moved here because there is a similar problem.
You can also solve the problem by converting the character to a known character.

```
x<-c("Sn. İLETİŞİM BİLGİLERİNİZ GUNCELLENMISTIR.")
x<-tolower(x)
x
[1] "sn. İletİşİm bİlgİlerİnİz guncellenmistir."
```

Let me add it as a picture. Because it may not be the same on every computer.

[image: tolower_my_computer]

*Actually expected output:*

[image]

When I suggested @drammock, I saw this.

```
x<-c("Sn. İLETİŞİM BİLGİLERİNİZ GUNCELLENMISTIR.")
x<-stri_trans_tolower(x, locale="tr_TR")
x
[1] "sn. iletişim bilgileriniz guncellenmıstır."
```

Again, I added the output of @drammock 's suggestion as a picture. The yellow areas in the picture are not the expected output.

[image: Stringi_output]

As a result, I found the UTF code of the character that could not be corrected by "tolower ()" and turned it into a character that was smoothly corrected by "tolower ()". Then I used "tolower ()" again and got the expected output. Thank you to everyone.

```
x<-c("Sn. İLETİŞİM BİLGİLERİNİZ GUNCELLENMISTIR.")
x<-gsub("\u0130","I",x,useBytes = FALSE)
x<-tolower(x)
x
[1] "sn. iletişim bilgileriniz guncellenmistir."
```

[image: expected_output]