# tolower () does not work for a Turkish character

Tags: r, lowercase, string-conversion, tolower

"İ" is a special and frequently used letter for Turkish.
I have data of multiple text types. The messages contain the following letters, which are translated versions of Turkish characters, with a mixed case. I have to shrink and transform to make the characters uniform. However, when you change the letter "İ" to lowercase, it becomes "I". That's why the code below can't find it.

```
fromDB$message<-mgsub(fromDB$message,c("ğ","ö","ş","ü","ç","ı"),c("g","o","s","u","c","i"),useBytes = FALSE)
```

As an example of messages, you can see the "x" below. Why can't the character in the example below be converted to lowercase by tolower()?

My current setting is `Sys.setlocale ("LC_CTYPE", "turkish").`

```
x<-c("Sn. İLETİŞİM BİLGİLERİNİZ GUNCELLENMISTIR.")
x<-tolower(x)
x
[1] "sn. İletİşİm bİlgİlerİnİz guncellenmistir."
```

Let me add it as a picture. Because it may not be the same on every computer.

[image: tolower_my_computer]

A solution is proposed by @drammock at the address below.

[Decapitalize UTF-8 special characters in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692198/decapitalize-utf-8-special-characters-in-r)

I tried, but this time, the letters "I" in the last word turned into wrong, as shown below.

```
library(stringi)
x<-c("Sn. İLETİŞİM BİLGİLERİNİZ GUNCELLENMISTIR.")
x<-stri_trans_tolower(x, locale="tr_TR")
x
[1] "sn. iletişim bilgileriniz guncellenmıstır."
```

It may be useful to add it as a picture again.

Expected output: `"sn. iletisim bilgileriniz guncellenmistir."`

[image]

Comment: Works as expected for me.

Comment: Let me add as image.

Comment: My current setting is Sys.setlocale ("LC_CTYPE", "turkish"). What should I write for Turkish?> Sys.setlocale(locale='tr_CA.UTF-8');
[1] ""
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale(locale = "tr_CA.UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "tr_CA.UTF-8" cannot be honored

Comment: Sys.setlocale(locale='tr_TR.UTF-8');
[1] ""
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale(locale = "tr_TR.UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "tr_TR.UTF-8" cannot be honored